# *nix shell: How to disable pipe buffering for ALL pipes in a command?

Tags: linux, shell, pipe, stdio

I want *every* pipe to be unbuffered, so I don't have to type `stdbuf -oL` for every piped command. When concocting commands with multiple pipes, it would be nice if there was a environment variable or something to enable it globally or at least for the remainder of the pipes in the command.

Yes I know about `unbuffer` and `stdbuf` but they need to be invoked for every pipe... I'm trying to save typing because I do this often.

Something like:

before:

```
stdbuf -oL command_1 | stdbuf -oL command_2 | stdbuf -oL command_3
```

after:

```
BUFFERING=-oL command_1 | command_2 | command_3
```

Answer (score 2):

The `stbuf` utility in GNU Coreutils works by setting the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable to force all descendant processes to open the `libstdbuf.so` shared library. In addition, it sets a few other variables to communicate parameters to that library.

You can just set those environment variables yourself.

Let's use `env` to see what they are:

```
$ stdbuf -oL env | grep -E '^LD_PRELOAD|^_STDBUF_'
_STDBUF_O=L
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/coreutils/libstdbuf.so
```

OK, so if we just `eval` the above, we got it:

```
$ eval $(stdbuf -oL env | grep -E '^LD_PRELOAD|^_STDBUF_')
$ echo $LD_PRELOAD 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/coreutils/libstdbuf.so
$ echo $_STDBUF_O 
L
```

One more thing; we have not told the shell to export these:

```
$ export LD_PRELOAD _STDBUF
```

Now the C `stdout` stream should be unbuffered in programs we run.

It seems simpler, however, to just run a nested shell with `setbuf`:

```
$ stdbuf -oL bash
$ echo $LD_PRELOAD
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/coreutils/libstdbuf.so
```

`exec` can be used to replace the original shell isntead:

```
$ exec stdbuf -oL bash
```